# Bash: my variable hold space separated values how can I create a table in db with it

Tags: bash

I am not able to debug the reason for the below syntax error:-

inventory.sh: line 94: syntax error near unexpected token `('
inventory.sh: line 94:`         query_string="INSERT INTO instance_detail ( instance_id, region ) values ('${instance[n]}' , '$i');"'

code near Line 94 in my script is written

```
for k in "${instance[@]}";
  do         
     query_string="INSERT INTO instance_detail ( instance_id, region ) values ('${instance[n]}' , '$i');"  (LINE:94)
    `echo "$query_string" | mysql -D $MYDB -u$MYUSER`
     done
     n=$n+1
```

done

The same insert query in sql runs fine.  kindly suggest!!!

Comment: 1. Remove back-ticks from `echo ...|mysql` line... & 
2. For debugging purpose, temporarily remove `| mysql...` part, to see what query is being generated....

Answer (score 0):

```
query_string="INSERT INTO instance_detail ( instance_id, region ) values ('$instance[n]' , '$i');"
```

OR

```
query_string="INSERT INTO instance_detail ( instance_id, region ) values ('${k}' , '$i');"
```

OR

```
query_string="INSERT INTO instance_detail ( instance_id, region ) values (${k} , '$i');"
```

OR

try to assign the value in a variable and try to use it

Answer (score 0):

If the `instance` array holds a list of instance_ids and you're not concerned about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), you don't need a for loop.

```
sql="INSERT INTO instance_detail (instance_id, region) values ('%s', '$i');\n"
printf "$sql" "${instance[@]}" | mysql -D $MYDB -u$MYUSER
```

The printf command will *reuse* the formatting template as many times as required to consume all the arguments it's given.